# Tikz graphs with typeset nodes

Tags: tikz-graphs

Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz,amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{graph}[multi]{
        1 -> 2;
        % this does not work:
        % $\mathbb{Q}$ -> $\mathbb{R}$;
        };
    \end{graph}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With regular tikz nodes it is straightforward, just stick it in the curly braces at the end of the node definition. But I don't understand how to map this to the graphs library. It appears only simple node names can be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `"` around the node names, e.g. `"$\mathbb{R}$"`. I don't know where/if this is documented, but it is used in some of the examples in the documentation, for example that on the first page of part IV of `pgfmanual.pdf`. (Page 364 in the manual dated December 20, 2013.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{graph}[multi]{
         "$\mathbb{Q}$" -> "$\mathbb{R}$";
        };
    \end{graph}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! This also works for `\includegraphics`.